# Control Menu in Java without case/break

Tags: java, while-loop, menu

I'm trying to create a menu in Java without case/breaks and am having two issues. (1) When I run the program with an input that should skip the .hasNextInt() while loop im having to re-input user data to get the program to end. (2) the .hasNextInt() while loop is not preventing the associated error of a user inputting the wrong type of data. So my code is still crashing with a string input instead of the user being caught in the while loop.

```
public static void menu(Library library){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int selection = 999999;

    while(selection < 1 || selection > 5){

        System.out.println("1. Display all books");
        System.out.println("2. Add a book");
        System.out.println("3. Delete a book");
        System.out.println("4. Exit the program");

        selection = keyboard.nextInt();

        while(!keyboard.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.println("Re-Enter an integer value");
            selection = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
```

Main just calls the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is close, but is handling non integer inputs incorrectly.  Consider using the following pattern:

```
while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
    keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("Re-Enter an integer value");
}
```

In your loop you were trying to consume an integer if the next token were not an integer.  Obviously, this doesn't make sense and won't work as intended.

The `Scanner#hasNextInt()` method will block until it can determine that the next token either was or was not an integer.  If not an integer, the above `while` loop will just consume the next token and repeat.  If the scanner determines that a valid integer is available, then you can use its value.

```
while (selection < 1 || selection > 5) {
    System.out.println("1. Display all books");
    System.out.println("2. Add a book");
    System.out.println("3. Delete a book");
    System.out.println("4. Exit the program");

    while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
        keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Re-Enter an integer value");
    }
    selection = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: this blows up or requires multiple inputs

Comment: @samgrey Different strokes for different folks.  Try the updated answer.

Comment: ah, got it, and it works, thank you for the help Tim!